# SQL Server 2005: how to copy database from one server to another (manually/programmatically)

Tags: sql-server, database, readonly

I am developing an ASP.NET-app which uses an SQL2005-DB - and from time to time I need to copy the db from the dev-environment to test or production - or vice-versa.
With SQL2000, I had written some batches to do that, but haven't had the time yet to find out how to do that under 2005, and did it manually. In SQL Mgmnt Studio, I would detach both dbs, then copy the MDF+LDF-Files from one server to the other and then re-attach the files. This has worked once or twice, but suddenly when I attach the db that was copied, it is in ReadOnly-Mode - which doesn't really help.

Why is that happening, am I doing something wrong - and how can I avoid that?
And if someone has .BAT to do that, even better! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Copy Database Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664(SQL.90).aspx) to do this manually.

Start it by right clicking a database in Management Studio and selecting Tasks > Copy Database... from the popup menu.

Comment: Thanks - but the wizard essentially seems to detach, copy, attach - and that's what I did manually and got the db in readonly-state. I'm not on the office right now, but will check when I'm back (probably tomorrow, MO latest) and post results...

Comment: There is an option in the Wizard to do the copying while allowing the copied database online - I assume that means it's not detached/reattached.