# Why is my SQL database marked readonly?

Tags: sql-server, database

i usually have my database updated in my development machine.
I need to transfer it to the client using some media like cd, dvd, pendrive or other.

When the client copies it and attaches it in his computer it shows readonly format and no transaction is allowed.

I don't know what i am missing to make it work?

Steps i follow:
1.) Copy database files from my computer to thumb drive
2.) hand Over it to client
3.) Client copies it to his machine
4.) removes previous one and Attaches the DB

Comment: you can't "copy" database files like that (when its running). "backup" or "detach" your DB, then copy that.

Comment: if i forget to do as you said then is there any way out for me

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389179/sql-server-2005-how-to-copy-database-from-one-server-to-another-manually-progra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to transfer it to the client
>   using some media like cd, dvd,
>   pendrive or other.
>
> When the client copies it and attaches
>   it in his computer it shows readonly
>   format and no transaction is allowed.

Check whether the FILES are read only to start with. Not sure - but if the MEDIA is read only, I think file copies are read only, too.

Comment: well after fine checking i found that the file wasn't readonly but my logged user hasn't permission for changing data in that particular file. Its NTFS file permission error...

Answer (score 0):

It isn't totally clear what you did, but what happens if you just remove the READONLY setting? Even if it fails, you may get a useful error message that helps to point you in the right direction:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET MULTI_USER
```

And you should probably review "Copying Databases to Other Servers" and `sp_detach_db` in Books Online to make sure that whatever exactly you're doing is actually supported. For what it's worth, BACKUP and RESTORE is often the easiest way to go in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Just give write permissions to the SQLite file in the assets folder (if you are using a database of yours).